# Missing ! causing "Module not found" - webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, node-modules, css-loader

I have node application that is using webpack bundler. Everytime I try to budle it, I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot resolve module 'test/qfla-server/node_modules/style-loader/addStyles.js' in /home/backman/!test/tta/app/renderer
resolve module test/tta/node_modules/style-loader/addStyles.js in /home/backman/!test/tta/app/renderer
  looking for modules in /home/backman/!test/tta/node_modules
    /home/backman/!test/tta/node_modules/test doesn't exist (module as directory)
  looking for modules in /home/backman/node_modules
    /home/backman/node_modules/test doesn't exist (module as directory)
[/home/backman/!test/tta/node_modules/test]
[/home/backman/node_modules/test]
```

There is clearly a problem with  wrong path to node_modules, test has '!' before it. This is happening only with style and css loaders. Is there some way where webpack would interpret this way correctly?

Comment: It is `css-loader` bug. You can disable source map generation for css to avoid this error.

Comment: Aren't source maps disabled by default?

Comment: Yes, it is disabled by default.  I thought bug was in `css-loader`, but it `style-loader`: https://github.com/webpack/style-loader/blob/master/index.js#L18

Comment: Well than is there way to get around it? I don't use source maps.

Comment: Only patching `style-loader` or just rename `!test` folder to `test`

Comment: Well, not gonna patch it :). Thank you .